# Отслеживание движения курсора мыши

Tags: javascript, html, mouse-event

Есть таблица - `<table>`. Пи движении мышью по таблице должна подсвечиваться строка таблицы, на которой остановилась мышь. Как это организовать (отследить движения курсора мыши)?

Comment: Псевдокласс `:hover`

Answer (score 2):

`tr:hover` в помощь

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:hover td {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <body>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  </body>
</table>
```